# How to create an instance of an interface in GWT?

Tags: gwt

How can i create an instance of an interface ?
example

```
@Connection(name="ClckCnt", version="1.0", description="Click Counter", maxsize=10000) 
public interface MyInterface extends DataService{


    @Update("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clickcount ("
      + "id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
      + "clicked INTEGER)")
  void initTable(VoidCallback callback);


     @Update("INSERT INTO clickcount (clicked) VALUES ({when.getTime()})")
  void insertClick(Date when, RowIdListCallback callback);
}

public class WebApp implements EntryPoint{

    MyInterface myInterface = GWT.create(MyInterface.class);

    public void onModuleLoad(){

    }
}
```

This kind of example i have from the [gwt-html5-database project](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/downloads/list). in this project is a sample application and they did it the same way but it doesnt work.
Somebody have an idea?
Greets.

Comment: GWT can't magically create an instance of any old interface. The `ClickCountDataService` in the example project works because it `extends DataService` and uses annotations which tells GWT how to generate an implementation.

Comment: Also, that code won't even _compile_. `myInterface.doSomething1(){
            Window.alert("Hello");
        }` is not syntactically valid Java.

Comment: ok thx, but where do you see these annotations?

Comment: On the `ClickCountDataService` interface.

Comment: i created an interface exactly the same like the interface ClickCountDataService which extends DataService and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred

You can either provide concrete implementations and chose the one to use depending on some properties (including, for example, user agent and/or locale), or use a generator. you can combine both: use a concrete implementation in some case, and a generator in another, depending on  properties.